# WordPress: Is there a way to find where your CSS class is stored in wordpress from chrome dev tool?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to swap these 2 tabs in my product page:

[image: image of the tabs]

**Learn More** tab should be where **Specification** tab is, but unfortunately I am unable to find where the *class* is located.

I have tried finding the class in `style.css` page in WordPress, but no luck.

```
<a href="#" ca1="cnt-32545" ca2="32529" class="tabUnover_4">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: Hover your mouse over `sharedcss` (see image). You will see the path of the file. https://i.imgur.com/drbOZVV.jpg

Comment: <li class="description_tab" id="tab-title-description" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-description">
     <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
    </li>



<li class="additional_information_tab active" id="tab-title-additional_information" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-additional_information">
     <a href="#tab-additional_information">Additional information</a>
    </li>

I just have to move the first code under the second code. Can I just edit this directly from editor ?

Comment: yes try to swap the li tag positions  that will solve your problem.

Comment: @Chilll007 There is a small problem. I know how to add css in wordpress you can just go to style.css and add additional css there But I don't see a file for HTML. Any idea where is the HTML files in Wordpress ?

Comment: if you provide website link so i can check and tell you in which file you will find that. if its woocommerce then you can check it in the woocommerce folders for this structure. or if it is in local you can find in the files for this structure

Comment: URL : http://newlayouthomepage1.bluebirdpackaging.com/product/custom-cake-printed-boxes/
Yes it's woo commerce tabs.
I am trying to learn how to save all edits I do in chrome dev tool in the wordpress so they are permeant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reorder the tabs using below code

```
 /**
     * Reorder product data tabs
     */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_reorder_tabs', 98 );
    function woo_reorder_tabs( $tabs ) {    
        $tabs['description']['priority'] = 5;           // Description second
        $tabs['additional_information']['priority'] = 10;   // Additional information third
        $tabs['reviews']['priority'] = 15;          // Reviews first
        return $tabs;
    }
```

you can add below in your themes `functions.php` file

found this on below [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

Comment: Thanks , This works! If we can some how still find where the HTML is located that would be awesome! I am looking in the chrome dev tool / source files it says it's in (index) https://imgur.com/a/vMH5UJw

Comment: it is in `tabs.php` file `/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php` this is the path

Comment: @Chill007 can you share how you figured this out ?

Comment: i just search for the woocommerce tabs then i got the file in file they are using for loop for printing the tabs which are available so i just search for changing their order.